# Regexp for removing certain columns

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I have an input of this format:

```
<apple1> <orange1> : <apple2> <orange2> : <apple3> <orange3> : ...
```

This input is of undefined length and consists of apple-orange pairs with varying orange and apple parts, separated by a colon.

I'd like to have this as an output:

```
<apple1> <orange1> : <orange2> : <orange3> : ...
```

I. e. all apple parts but the first removed.

Each apple part is 14 characters wide, each orange part is 19 characters wide.

I tried things like this:

```
sed -r 's/.{14}(.{19}):/\1:/g'
```

But this always ran into problems skipping the first apple part.

Can anybody provide a regexp solving this task?

Real world example input:

```
appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo
foofoofoofoofobarbarbarbarbarbarb:foofoofoofoofobarbarbarbarbarbarb:foofoofoofoofobarbarbarbarbarbarb
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxooooooooooooooooooo:ppppppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq:nnnnnnnnnnnnnnttttttttttttttttttt
```

Output should be this:

```
appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:orangeorangeorangeo:orangeorangeorangeo
foofoofoofoofobarbarbarbarbarbarb:barbarbarbarbarbarb:barbarbarbarbarbarb
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxooooooooooooooooooo:qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq:ttttttttttttttttttt
```

Comment: where is the `pipe symbol`?

Comment: Sorry, editing went wild.  I meant a colon.  Question is edited.

Comment: How are you storing the output? This matters because you can do something like `head -c 14` to get the first apple into the output.

Comment: For that matter, what is your input like?

Comment: @Alfe can you  post a real example? I mean, with real apple/orange, 3-4 columns are enough

Comment: @Kent I added an example input and output; I now see that I should have reduced the widths to 3 and 5 instead of 14 and 19 ;-)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah, well, I want to have a regexp to do this, not frickle around with other shell tools like `head` (which won't easily work for the remaining lines, etc.).

Comment: You might need two regex in sed then, one for the first line, the other to run always. You can do that with the -e flag if I am not mistaken. Not sure what the regex would be in that case though.

Comment: Also, why are you so insistent on regex when your field widths are well known ahead of time?

Comment: @MadPhysicist My field widths are well known but not their number.  There could be any number of apple-orange pairs in each line.  If you know a different way of stripping all columns c for which offset1 + n * width < c < offset2 + n * width for every possible n is true, feel free to suggest it ;-)  I tried `cut` first but found giving endless lists to `-c` not so feasible.

Comment: @Alfe. Point taken. I still think fiddling the first line separately is going to be the simplest way to go.

Comment: @MadPhysicist But I don't want the first line to be treated any different than the remaining ones ... *confused*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex to sed was almost correct. Just match ":_14_19" over and over and remove the 14 part. (Note: I use commas as regex delimiters below because they're easier to read.)

```
$ export A='appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:foofoofoofoofobarbarbarbarbarbarb:foofoofoofoofobarbarbarbarbarbarb:foofoofoofoofobarbarbarbarbarbarb:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxooooooooooooooooooo:ppppppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq:nnnnnnnnnnnnnnttttttttttttttttttt'
$ echo $A | sed -Ee 's,:.{14}(.{19}),:\1,g'
appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:orangeorangeorangeo:orangeorangeorangeo:barbarbarbarbarbarb:barbarbarbarbarbarb:barbarbarbarbarbarb:ooooooooooooooooooo:qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq:ttttttttttttttttttt
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that will do in case nothing better pops up.  I was hoping not to rely on the fact that there are colons in certain lines, but as they are part of my spec, I think this is the shortest solution.

Answer (score 1):

This job is more suitable to `awk` as input file is well structured in rows and columns using a known delimiter i.e. `colon`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) $i = substr($i, 15)} 1' file

appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:orangeorangeorangeo:orangeorangeorangeo
foofoofoofoofobarbarbarbarbarbarb:barbarbarbarbarbarb:barbarbarbarbarbarb
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxooooooooooooooooooo:qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq:ttttttttttttttttttt
```

This awk command uses `:` as input+output delimiter and starting from 2nd field in each record it sets each field to a substring of same field from `15th` position.

Answer (score 0):

With perl..

**Our Input**: `appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo`

lets assume 
`a=appleappleappl` (14 characters)
`b=orangeorangeorangeo` (19 characters)
`c=appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo` (rest of the line, which is a repeating combination of `a` and `b`.

**Expected output:** Before the fist colon (`:`), both `a` and `b` are kept and after the first colon, only `b` is kept.
${a}${b}:${b}:${b}:.... (please correct me if I am wrong)

*So here it is once again, to recap, both the input and output.*

*Our Input:* `appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo`

*Expected Output:* `appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:orangeorangeorangeo:orangeorangeorangeo`

*Please try this script:* (As mentioned earlier, this is using perl and not shell).

```
%_Host@User> cat apple.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  chomp $_ ;
  my @tmp = split /:/, $_ ;
  my ($a,$b) = (substr($tmp[0],0,14), substr($tmp[0],14,19)) ;
  my $str = "$a"."$b" ;

  foreach my $i (1..$#tmp) {
    $tmp[$i] =~  s/$a//g ;
    $str .= ":"."$tmp[$i]"  ;
  }
  print "$str\n" ;
}
%_Host@User>
```

**Script Output:**

```
%_Host@User> cat td_apple |./apple.pl
appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:orangeorangeorangeo:orangeorangeorangeo
foofoofoofoofobarbarbarbarbarbarb:barbarbarbarbarbarb:barbarbarbarbarbarb
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxooooooooooooooooooo:ppppppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq:nnnnnnnnnnnnnnttttttttttttttttttt
```

*Sample Data:*

```
%_Host@User> cat td_apple
appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo:appleappleapplorangeorangeorangeo
foofoofoofoofobarbarbarbarbarbarb:foofoofoofoofobarbarbarbarbarbarb:foofoofoofoofobarbarbarbarbarbarb
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxooooooooooooooooooo:ppppppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq:nnnnnnnnnnnnnnttttttttttttttttttt
%_Host@User>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Wow.  That's a lot.  Thank you but the whole idea of using a regexp was to keep it small and simple.  Sorry, but your solution is way out of line in that aspect.

Comment: You are right! Can't disagree there. Yes, this solution is not small ;P.

Comment: @Alfe: May I ask you, how much data of this particular type do you need to process? what is your scenario, possible to share some info.

Comment: I have about 40 lines of input (per quarter, to be precise ;-)